# When to put factory() method into factoried object and when put factory() method to separated class?

Tags: php

Is it ok to put `factory()` method to the factoried object's class?

```
class User {

    public static function factory($id) {
       return new User($id);
    }

    private function __construct($id) {

    }

}
```

And when consider placing factory() method into separated class?

```
class User {

    public function __construct($id) {

    }

}

class UserFactory {

    public static function factory($id) {
        return new User($id)
    }

}
```

I can't see any benefits of using additional class for factory, but I consider that there are some benefits I don't know about. :)

When to put `factory()` method into factoried object and when put `factory()` method to separated class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a **static** creator method there is not much use in putting in into a factory.

---

It's only really useful to put factory method in it's own class if it **isn't static** and you want to inject it somewhere.

```
class User {

    public static function __construct($id) {

    }

}

class UserFactory {

    public function factory($id) {
        return new User($id)
    }

}
```

---

```
class SomethingUserReleated {
    public function __construct(UserFactory $factory) {
        $this->userFactory = $factory;
    }

    public function iNeedToCreateAnUserForSomething() {
        $userOne = $this->userFactory->factory(1233);
        $userTwo = $this->userFactory->factory(123533);
    }
}
```

---

Since you can't to the above with static methods.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage with putting the factory method inside the class itself is protecting the class from being instantiated without using the factory method:

```
class User {

    public static function factory($id) {
       return new User($id);
    }

    private function __construct($id) {
        // Now, only the factory method within this class can call this method.
        // (Additionally, this method was static, which it shouldn't.)
    }

}
```

I let other add to this with advantages of the opposite solution.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the factory methods into separate class allows you to separate object-methods and factory-specific methods (that are only needed while creating a new object).

```
class User {
  public static function __construct($id, $name){
    // call this directly or via Factory
  }
}

class UserFactory {
  private static function randomName(){
    // return some random name
  }

  public static function factory($id){
    return new User($id, UserFactory::randomName());
  }
}
```